# Microcosm and mind affecting abilities

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, psionics, illusion

The power *[microcosm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/microcosm.htm)* causes a creature’s senses to be pinched off from the real world and completely fabricated from within its own mind. My question is whether telepathy and mind-affecting spells and powers would affect such a creature if they don't rely on the senses but the creature's mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If microcosm targets a single creature, that creature’s senses are
>   pinched off from the real world if it currently has 100 or fewer hit
>   points. The subject’s senses are all completely fabricated from within
>   its own mind, though it may not realize this. In reality, the subject
>   sprawls limply, drooling and mewling, and eventually dies of thirst
>   and starvation without care. The subject lives within its own made-up
>   world until the time of its actual death.

This means that his Sight, Touch, Taste, Feel, and Smell is fabricated by the effect.

> Manifesting microcosm a second time on an affected creature turns its
>   sensory pathways outward once more. Otherwise, only very potent powers
>   (such as psychic chirurgery or reality revision) or similar effects
>   (such as miracle or wish) can undo the mental crosswiring that this
>   power brings about.

Reading both of these effects in the spell, especially the second, the target does seem to be able to be affected by further psychic manipulation, though what effects that might have considering he is, as the spell states, mentally crosswired, is unknown. Those affects would also, as the spell states, have to be very potent; the two spells listed are of 9th level (psion/wilder and telepath, respectively). One could assume then that anything under 9th is probably going to have little to no effect due to the mental damage of microcosm.